# Is there a way to access a JavaScript event inside an onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, events, html

Suppose I need to write an onclick handler in an *attribute*, like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='DoSomething(); event.stopPropagation(); return false;'>
    ...</a>
```

I know this is bad form, but suppose for the moment that I have to use an attribute.

Unfortunately `event` is not defined. I tried `e` and that is not defined either. Is there any way to access the event object inside the attribute, or any other way to stop the event propagation?

Comment: Works fine for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: This JSFiddle only shows one alert box on Google Chrome (Mac, 13.0.782.107): http://jsfiddle.net/xfZvK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you get the event object depends on the browser. Some (all?) IE versions put it in `window.event` but everyone else passes it as an argument. So, you end up having to do a silly little dance like this:

```
function DoSomething(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Do useful work.
    return false;
}
```

And then set up the `onclick` like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DoSomething(event)">
```

I also switch to `javascript:void(0)` so you don't have the usual "`#` interpreted as an in-page fragment" problems.

Comment: Please use `var event = ...`.

Comment: @pimvdb: Why? Having it in the function's argument list is sufficient to avoid an accidental global.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass it into the function itself, like so:

```
<a href='#' onclick='DoSomething(event); return false;'>...</a>

function DoSomething(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Where did you get the `event` reference from in the first place? And if you do have it, why can't you use it in the `onclick` attribute directly?

Comment: Whoa, this actually worked. Sorry about the earlier downvote, I did this wrong...

Comment: @Samir: I wish I could downvote a comment, you're not making any sense. Try this in a non-IE browser: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KSnmP/

Comment: @Timwi I edited the answer. Feel free to remove your downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @mu: That works fine. As does `<a href="#" onclick="console.log(event);">pancakes</a>`. There's no need for the function. If you have a reference to `event`, you can use it anywhere. Not just in a function.

Comment: @Samir: And what does that have to do with "Where did you get the `event` reference"?

Comment: @mu: Timwi already knew to use `event`. Passing it to a function does nothing more unless you're doing more work in the function (as in your own answer). All this answer does is imply that a function will magically fix the reference to `event`.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on browser, `event` creating and handling is handled differently.

IE creates the global event object when the click happens. [FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) doesn't create the *global* `event` object but passes it to the function as the first argument.

But in your case, simply saying `return false` will cancel the link action (if that's what you intend to do).

```
<a href='#' onclick='DoSomething(); return false;'>    ...</a>
```

Comment: @Timwi: What browser are you using? It is not undefined in IE9

Comment: The `window.event` thing is an old IE-ism. Not my downvote though.

Comment: @Mrchief: If IE is the only browser in which you test your answers before you post them, you need to rethink. Also, your edited post is still wrong, `return false` does not cancel the bubbling, it only cancels the link’s click action (to follow the link).

Comment: @Timwi: You're right. I meant cancelling the link action, I'll edit my post to correct this. I also (wrongly) presumed that you knew about the event argument, just that for some reason you wanted to do it in the attribute.